# When uploading a package to the Windows dev store, it says it is unsuitable despite following the manual?

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-dev-center

[How can I fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avgng.png) I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before packaging your app, you need to test your app in .Net Native compilation environment to improve your app's runtime performance.

You could right-click your project > click `property` > select `Build` > check `Compile with .NET Native tool chain`. 
[image]

By default, the **Release** build configuration enables the .NET native toolchain so you could test your app in release build.

After that, you could package your app following [Packaging UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#before-packaging-your-app) and upload it to Dev Center.